# PHP Email Form Animation

Tags: php, html, forms

Im trying to create a email form that slides up from the bottom of the page when you click a certain button, If you click it again, It will simply slide back down, But I am having issues, When clicking send, It doesnt validate like it should and also reloads the page more than once, Heres the page: http://harryfelton.host56.com

I am sure I have messed something up in the php, Here is the entire index file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/primary.css"> <!--Address Using URL to prevent no styling when slash is typed-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/tabIcon.ico">
<title>Harry Felton | Welcome</title>
</head>

<script>
    function toggleAbout(){
        if ($("#center").hasClass("up")) {
            $("#about").slideToggle(500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#center").css({
                    transform: 'translateY(10px)',
                })
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $("#center").css({
                transform: 'translateY(-75px)',
            })      
            setTimeout(function() {
            $("#about").slideToggle(500);
        }, 1000);

        }
        $($("#center").toggleClass("up"))
    };

    function toggleContact(){
        $("#contactForm").toggleClass("hardHide");
        $("#contactForm").toggleClass("hidden");
    }
</script>

<body style="display:none;" class="pg-index">
    <div class="overwrap">
        <div id="centerNoY">
            <div id='cssmenu'>
                <ul>
                   <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
                   <li class='has-sub'><a onclick="loadPage('portfolio', 'body');"><span>Portfolio</span><img src="Images/arrow.png"></a>
                      <ul>
                         <li class='has-sub'><a onclick="loadPage('programs', 'body');"><span>Programs</span></a>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a onclick="loadPage('SecuritySP', 'body');" ><span>HbombOS Security Suite</span></a></li>
                               <!--<li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a></li>-->
                            </ul>
                         </li>
                         <li class='has-sub'><a onclick="loadPage('projects', 'body');"><span>Projects</span></a>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a onclick="loadPage('HbombOS', 'body');"><span>HbombOS</span></a></li>
                               <li class='last'><a onclick="loadPage('IA', 'body');"><span>Industrial Advance</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </li>
                      </ul>
                   </li>
                   <li><a onclick="toggleAbout();"><span>About</span></a></li>
                   <li class='last'><a onclick="toggleContact();"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="center">
            <h1 id="title1">Welcome</h1>
            <h2 id="title2">Harry Felton</h2>
            <h2 id="subTitle">Auckland | New Zealand</h2>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div id="about" style="display: none;">
                <p>Hi, My name is Harry and I am an amateur programmer, I just do it as a hobby until I can actually take it as a course, I have created many programs, and love doing it, I am also into ComputerCraft which is a mod for Minecraft that adds programmable computers.<br><br>This website domain was initially created around September 2014, It took about a week to create, It was awesome, As it was the first time I had ever used HTML, CSS or JavaScript. On the 20th November I chose to completely recreate the website, So I deleted all files, And now... Here we are.<br><br>My absolute favorite thing to do in this world is code, I enjoy making, distributing and using my programs, And the feedback is always awesome, If you feel like leaving feedback, then click HERE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contactForm" class="hidden hardHide">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
            <title>Contact Us</title>
            <div id="mainPageCont">
            <?php error_reporting(0); ?>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['Email'])): ?>
                <?php
                        // This is where you process the email and display the thank you page
                        $to      = 'harryfelton12@gmail.com';
                        $subject = 'ALERT! Website Form Submission';
                        $message = 'Users Name: '.strip_tags($_POST['Name'])."\n"; 
                        $message .= 'Users Email: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email'])."\n";
                        $message .= 'Submitted Message: '.strip_tags($_POST['Comment'])."\n";
                        $message .= 'Message Type: ';
                        $message .= ($_POST['Type'] !== 'Other')? $_POST['Type']."\n": strip_tags($_POST['option'])."\n";
                        $headers = 'From: noReply@harryfelton.com' . "\r\n" .
                            'Reply-To: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n";
                        // If the mail is successful, display thanks else display failed
                        ?>
                        <?php if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)): ?>
                            <?php 
                                $replyTo = strip_tags($_POST['Email']);
                                $replySubject = 'Thank You For Leaving A Comment ';
                                $replySubject .= strip_tags($_POST['Name']);
                                $replyMess = 'Thanks for leaving a message on www.harryfelton.host56.com' . "\n\n";
                                $replyMess .= 'If you didnt use the email of: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . ' then please contact us by replying to this email' ."\n\n";
                                $replyMess .= 'Although if you did then you can expect a reply to your comment in two working days if the comment requires a reply' ."\n";
                                $replyHeaders = 'From: alert@harryForms.com' . "\r\n" .
                            'Reply-To: ' . 'contact@harryfelton.host56.com' . "\r\n";
                                mail($replyTo, $replySubject, $replyMess, $replyHeaders);
                            ?>
                                                        <div id="comments_form">
                            <!--Message Sent! Slide Email Up! -->
                    <?php else: ?>
                      <div id="comments_form">
                      <!--There was an error, let then know that it couldnt be sent-->
                      <script>alert("Your message can not be sent at this time, Please try again later and ensure your internet connection is active");</script>
                    <?php endif ?>
            </div>
            <?php  else: ?>
            <form method="post" id="comments_form">
                <h2>Please Leave Some Feedback, It Helps!</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Your Name
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="Name"
                            value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Name'])? $_POST['Name'] : ''; ?>" />
                        <?php if(in_array('Name', $validation)): ?>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['Name']; ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                    <div class="context">
                        e.g. John Smith or Jane Doe
                    </div>
                    <!--end .context-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Your Email
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="Email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Email'])? $_POST['Email'] : ''; ?>" />
                        <?php if(in_array('Email', $validation)): ?>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['Email']; ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                    <div class="context">
                        We wont spam you! We only need this to reply to questions you might pose
                    </div>
                    <!--end .context-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Type Of Message
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="radio" name="Type" onChange="GetValue(this)"  value="Feedback" checked="checked" /> 
                        Feedback <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="Type" onChange="GetValue(this)" value="Feature Request" <?php echo (isset($_POST['Type']) && $_POST['Type'] == 'Feature Request')? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                        Feature Request<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="Type" onChange="GetValue(this)" value="Bug Report" <?php echo (isset($_POST['Type']) && $_POST['Type'] == 'Bug Report')? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                        Bug Report<br>
                        <input type="radio" name="Type" onChange="GetValue(this)" value="Other" id="other" <?php echo (isset($_POST['Type']) && $_POST['Type'] == 'Other')? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
                        Other<br />
                      <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="option" name="option" <?php echo (isset($_POST['option']))? $_POST['option']: ''; ?> />
                      <?php if(in_array('Type', $validation)): ?>
                        <span class="error"> <?php echo $error_messages['Type']; ?> </span>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                    <div class="context">
                        This is to help us better respond to your message
                    </div>
                    <!--end .context-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Your Message
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input2">
                        <textarea id="Comment" name="Comment" class="mess"><?php echo isset($_POST['Comment'])? $_POST['Comment'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                        <?php if(in_array('Comment', $validation)): ?>
                        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['Comment']; ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->

                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <script>
                // This function just checks if the 'other' gets checked
            function GetValue(ThisVal) {
                var Writing = $(ThisVal).val();
                // This just shows you what is happening via the feedback div
                $('#feederback').html(Writing);
                if (Writing == 'Other') {
                    // If other, disable the submit
                    $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
                    // Fade in the message textarea
                    $('#option').fadeIn('fast');
                    // Check the message area to see if there is text in it already.
                    // If there is text enable the submit button
                    CheckVal();
                } else {
                    // If not other, fade out the message
                    $('#option').fadeOut('fast');
                    // Enable the submit button
                    $('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
                }
            }

            function CheckVal() {
                var SetMess = $('#option').val();
                $('#feedback').html(SetMess);

                if (SetMess !== '')  {
                        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                else {
                        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
            }
            // As one types, check that the message is not empty
            $('#option').keyup(function () {
                CheckVal();
            });
            // As one clicks into the field, see if it has content
            $('#option').click(function () {
                CheckVal();
            });

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        // validate form
                        $("#comments_form").validate({
                            // This will allow you to extend the validator functions
                            invalidHandler: 
                                    function(form, validator) {
                                      //  $("#get_online").val("CHECK");
                                },
                            rules: {
                                // For every named input that you want to validate,
                                // you create a little set of prefs
                                Name: {
                                    required: true,
                                },
                                Email: {
                                            required: true,
                                            email: true
                                        },

                                Type: { required: true },
                                Comment: { required: true },
                                },
                            messages: {
                                    // Here are just the custom messages you can modify per field
                                    Name: {
                                            required: 'Please Enter Your Name', 
                                        },
                                    Email: {
                                            required: 'Please Enter An Email',
                                            email: 'Email address not valid',
                                        },
                                    Type: { required: 'Please Select A Type' },
                                    Comment: { required: 'Please Enter A Message'},
                                },
                        });
                    });
            </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/element.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/pageNav.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            fadeIn("body");
        });
    </script>
    <script>changeWelcome("#title1");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Heres the CSS file that affects this issue:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
}


.pg-index #center {
    transition: 1s transform;   
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}

a.url{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #0FF;
    cursor:pointer;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;    
}

h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
}

a.url:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

body, html{
    background-color: #09F; /*Light Blue Color */
    font-color: #FFF;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

/*Dynamic Page Elements*/

#contactForm.hidden{
    top: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
}

#contactForm.hardHide{
    display: none;
}

#contactForm {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; 
    border: medium solid #930;
    z-index: 100;
}

#center {
    text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT: I adjusted the code, It prevents the reload, Although the form still is allowing no data to be validated, It should tell me I need to enter it...

If any of you have any suggestions or better yet, a fix then please let me know, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the answer, but just something I noticed playing around with your code.  In the section after thanks for your message.

```
function redirectPage() {
    location.href="index.html"  
};
```

You don't have an index.html on that page.

Comment: Ahhh, yes thanks, I noticed that shortly after I posted the question, Thanks though :)